# Moving model pieces around the model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a parent model and it has around 50 gameObjects as children. I am writing a script to move the children gameObjects slowly at random positions away from the parent, but close to the parent. Such that it looks like a mesh is splitting slowly.
I have to attach this script to each of its children since the order for few meshes are `parent->children->subchildren`. The subchildren are not to be found when I use `foreach (Transform child in parent.transform)`. How do I achieve it such that I can add the script to the parent and all the children will have an effect on it?

```
     public float speed = 2.0f;
     public float Position_x;
     public float Position_z;
     public Vector3 FinalPos;
     void Start()
     {
         Position_x = Random.Range(-1.5f, 3f);
         Position_z = Random.Range(-1.5f, 3f);
         FinalPos= new Vector3(Position_x , transform.position.y, Position_z);
     }
 
     void Update()
     {
             
         transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, FinalPos, Time.deltaTime * speed)

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it with `foreach (Transform child in transform)` not `foreach (Transform child in parent.transform)` because we use `transform.parent` to access the parent's transform but not `parent.transfom` and `transform` for the object's transform.

because that **transform** is an object that stores the object, the parent and children transforms and many other things, you can :

```
     public List<GameObject> Children; // you can store that children objects if you intend to use them later.
     foreach (Transform child in transform)
     {
         if (child.tag == "Tag")// also if you need to specify a specific child using Tags
         {
             Children.Add(child.gameObject);// to add the object in that List

             //your operations or movement...
         }
     }
```

> don't forget to assign this script to the parent object.

**EDIT**

you can also use `transform.GetChild(index)` to get a specific child's transform, where the index is the number of child's transform (that index is a zero-based)